# Wordpress + Custom Taxonomy + Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, wp-list-categories

I know there has been similar questions before, but I can't find a solution and feel that mine might be slightly unique.

I have a few custom post types + taxonomies to go with.

**Post Type** = Product
**Taxonomy** = Product_Categories

My Test Site is: http://tech.stickystudios.ca/

If you are able to visit, *Products -> Broadcast*, click on a category on the left...

I am un-able to get anything to show up in these pages, no matter how I play with the URL.

Some Extra Information on Plugins being used.
- Magic Fields 2
- Query Wrangler
- Woo Commerce (for the 'components' page)

It seems to be a trend on my entire site things with 'categories' just don't want to 'list' properly.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've understood, your trying to upgrade your permalinks to utilize the custom post type and taxonomies in order to cross-examine them.

*The simplest method to use this is...*

**example.com/?cat=1**

OR

**example.com/?cat=1,2,3&tag=tag1,tag2**

Which will only **include** the terms, not **require** the category terms and tag slugs, but will require posts to have at least one term and tag. The post type defaults to Posts. In order in utilize the permalinks with post types and taxonomies you have to identify and use the slugs and IDs (category ids only).

Categories = **cat=1,2,3** (IDs)

Tags = **tag=tag_slug1,tag_slug2,tag_slug3**

(Custom) Post Types = **post_type=post_type_slug**

Custom Taxonomies =  **taxonomy_slug=term_slug1,term_slug2,term_slug4**

*More advanced methods of using this...*

**example.com/?post_type=posts&cat=21,32&tag=one&taxonomy_slug=term_slug1,term_slug2**

OR

**example.com/?post_type=foods&cat=12,43&tag=fruit,veg&color_taxonomy=red,white,purple**

Using this method will allow you to search within a specific post type (which allows only one slug), include terms within the taxonomies, as well as require at least one of the IDs and slugs being used in each taxonomy. One known plugin that utilizes this and offers a dynamic navigation sidebar is [Taxonomy Picker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-picker/). Which should allow you experiment with the URL navigation. Another plugin that will allow you to create lists of posts and *pages* is [Advanced Post List](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-post-list/). Which can list multiple post types and include/require taxonomies as well as add terms from the current post/page. It requires a little more work to create your lists, but it goes a step further than what WordPress has to offer.